# trying to copy but exclude some fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

my below function is working, but there are certain fields which i do not want to copy over, i am thing of adding the data-attr to those fields which will not be carried over

why i am doing this is because when i copy it over, regardless of the positioning of the fields, it enters the data in those fields where it should enter it

```
function copyAddress() 
  {
      var contactaddress = document.querySelectorAll("#contactaddress input");
      var paymentaddress = document.querySelectorAll("#paymentaddress input");

      var contactaddressSelects = document.querySelectorAll("#contactaddress select");
      var paymentaddressSelects = document.querySelectorAll("#paymentaddress select");
      if (document.getElementById("sameAddr").checked) 
      {
        for (var i = 0; i < contactaddress.length; i++) 
        {
          paymentaddress[i + 1].value = contactaddress[i].value;
        } 

        for (var i = 0; i < contactaddressSelects.length; i++) 
        {
          paymentaddressSelects[i + 1].value = contactaddressSelects[i].value;
        } 
      }
  }
```

Comment: your problem is not clear, what you want to copy and what you dont want to copy, and show your html code

Comment: all i need is if the attribute `data-nocopy="1"` is defined in the target input or select fields, it will ignore the values of those fields and where `data-nocopy="0"`, it will fill values to those fields

Comment: `$("[data-nocopy=0]")`

Comment: where to add this?